# Is there a way to make a kinematic Rigidbody that is already moving follow another non-kinematic Rigidbody's position?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

Currently trying to make a very basic stabilization system for a ragdoll using a inverted pendulum.
Essentially I can only make the pendulum follow the players ragdoll if it's not using the Mathf.PingPong function, which is the how the pendulum is functioning. It functions by moving the base of the pendulum up and down really quickly, which keeps the weight on top of the pendulum centered unless the weight of the players body pulls it out of balance.
In the following code, I attempt to get the position of the player prefab and have the _base follow that position, but at the same time it's performing the pingpong and assigning itself to the same position, overwriting the initial movement.

How would I go about getting the _base Rigidbody to follow the Rigidbody that I've attached to the parent object in the prefab, while also performing its pingpong function?

Here's my [code](https://pastie.io/qyqaqc.cs):

```
using UnityEngine;
 
public class Pendulum : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    public Rigidbody _base;
    public Rigidbody _player;
 
    [Space]
    [SerializeField]
    public float _speed = 200;
 
    public Vector3 pointA;
    public Vector3 pointB;
   
 
    void Start()
    {
        _base = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        pointA = new Vector3(0, .2f, 0);
        pointB = new Vector3(0, .5f, 0);
    }
 
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        _base.MovePosition(_TestStabliziedPlayer.position);
        float time = Mathf.PingPong(Time.time * _speed, 1);
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(pointA, pointB, time);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `Hinge Joint` to connect two rigidbodys like a chain, you can see unity's documentation about Hinge joint here :
[Unity documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-HingeJoint.html)

You can use this tutorial for your project, i think it will be very useful

[Tutorial Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fltt-j655MI)

Comment: I should have clarified that I already tried using joints, but perhaps I wasn't using the hinge joint correctly. I will look into this and see if thats the case, otherwise I may still be having the issue

Comment: :v if you have problem with hinge joint, just comment below, i'll help you

Comment: I don't think Joints work for kinematic Rigidbodies ... @NawtZach does the rigidbody really need to stay kinematic? As soon as you attach the joint you could make it non-kinematic as well

Comment: @derHugo I attempted that, but it causes the pendulum base to rotate and when I lock it's rotational axis, it completely breaks the system. The pendulum stabilization only works when the pendulums base is kinematic.